# Subset a dataframe with dynamic dates by date range in R

Tags: r

I have the dataframe below:

```
dates <- data.frame(rep(
  seq(as.Date('2017-01-01'), as.Date('2017-12-31'), by = 'days'), 
  times = 1))
colnames(dates)<-"day"
```

And I would like to subset it by the last 2 weeks. The thing is that I do not want to use something like:

```
dates[day>="2017-18-02" & day<="2017-05-02"]
```

because the dataframe will be updated over time and the last date will be changing.

Comment: Can you show the expected output

Comment: Where do `"2013-08-02"` and `"2013-11-01"` come from? It's neither a week long, or contains the final or first value in the data...

Comment: `Sys.Date()` gives you the current date. `Sys.Date() - 7` gives you last week's date. Does this help?

Comment: those dates are just example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution with lubridate and dplyr

```
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)

testset %>%
filter(week(testset$date) == max(week(testset$date)))
```

Comment: and if it is 2 weeks?

Comment: Add an or statement to the filter to get the previous week as well. Sorry for the poor formatting. `testset %>%`
`filter(week(testset$date) == max(week(testset$date)) | week(testset$date) == max(week(testset$date)) - 1)`

Comment: I updated my example in order 2 include 2 weeks. Your answer gives me 10 days

Comment: can you confirm it?

Comment: `dates %>%
filter(day > max(dates$day) - days(14))` My previous code is based off the week number. Based off the new example this code will give you last 14 days.

Answer (score 0):

We can extract the week and create a logical vector

```
testset[testset[, {i1 <- as.numeric(format(date, "%W")); .I[i1 == max(i1)]}]]
```

If it is more than one week

```
testset[testset[, {i1 <- as.numeric(format(date, "%W"))
                   .I[i1 %in% tail(unique(sort(i1)), 2)] }]]
```

Comment: and if it is 2 weeks?

Comment: @firm023 In that case you can just `sort` and get the `i1 %in% tail(sort(i1), 2)`

Comment: @firmo23. I updated based on your comment.  Is this what you wanted

Comment: I updated my example dataset in order to include 2 weeks. I do not think that works

Answer (score 0):

You could create a `Week` column from the `date` and filter for `max(Week)`

```
    library(data.table)
    #> Warning: package 'data.table' was built under R version 3.6.2

    testset <- data.table(date=as.Date(c("2013-07-02","2013-08-03","2013-09-04",
                                     "2013-10-05","2013-11-06")), 
                      yr = c(2013,2013,2013,2013,2013), 
                      mo = c(07,08,09,10,11),
                      da = c(02,03,04,05,06), 
                      plant = LETTERS[1:5], 
                      product = as.factor(letters[26:22]), 
                      rating = runif(25))

    testset$Week <- format(testset$date, "%W")

    testset[Week == max(Week)]
    #>          date   yr mo da plant product    rating Week
    #> 1: 2013-11-06 2013 11  6     E       v 0.7794414   44
    #> 2: 2013-11-06 2013 11  6     E       v 0.4971975   44
    #> 3: 2013-11-06 2013 11  6     E       v 0.6272580   44
    #> 4: 2013-11-06 2013 11  6     E       v 0.3748460   44
    #> 5: 2013-11-06 2013 11  6     E       v 0.6683196   44
```

Comment: and if it is 2 weeks?

Comment: Added my own data to include multiple weeks. For last 2 weeks, change to    `testset[Week >= (max(Week)-1)]`

Comment: Also change the `week` column creation statement to `testset$Week <- as.numeric(format(testset$date, "%W"))`